# Get all product category names from WooCommerce product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently trying to receive all product category names. This is my code:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'number'   => $job_id
);

$product_categories = get_terms( $args );
```

This works fine but this returns the whole object but I just want the names to be returned. So I've modified my code this way:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'number'   => $job_id,
    'fields'  => 'name'
);

$product_categories = get_terms( $args );
```

But now I get no results. Whats wrong here?

```
["name"]=> string(7) "Cat1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would work with [`get_term_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)

Also , have you ever try this ? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/150032/7394